# Crashlytics NDK for external subproject dependency

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm trying to implement Crashlytics for my project which uses NDK/JNI. However the JNI part is in a project loaded externally like this in `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app', ':core'
project (':core').projectDir = new File(rootDir, '../core')
```

I read that for some time Crashlytics should find the symbols automatically without the need to specify `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut`. It didn't work for my scenario, when I called `./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbols{flavor}Debug` it complained about wrong androidNdkOut.

So I added those paths explicitly in the app's `build.gradle`:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut '../../core/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut '../../core/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj'
    manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

Crashlytics does find them right now and the `crashlyticsUploadSymbols{flavor}Debug` returns success. But it doesn't work properly. Some of the errors are not reported at all in the Crashlytics console, the rest is not deobfuscated. Also Crashlytics shows something like this in the logcat:

```
W/CrashlyticsCore: No minidump data found in directory /data/data/com.example.app/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-ndk/native/1513601249792
```

**What should I do for my configuration to properly log the NDK exceptions in Crashlytics console?**

Answer (score 2):

Configuration that you specified in `build.gradle` is not correct.

**androidNdkOut** should point to object files, something like `'../../core/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj'`

**androidNdkLibsOut** should point to actual libraries. in your case, most probably `'../../core/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/release/folders/2000/3/main/lib'`

Comment: I found a similar path in my project and indeed it contains the libs. Changed it in configuration, run crashlyticsUploadSymbols..., opened the console but the crashlogs still only tell me the library name and "Missing" on every stacktrace line. Maybe it only works for new crashes?

Comment: Tried to crash the JNI layer with some simple null pointer but it didn't appear in crashlytics console.